# Yii2 advance for Multi version app shared session

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have 2 versions of the app. v1 and v2. Currently, both apps use Yii2 basic template and different servers. Now we need to merge all apps. So users can move from v1 to v2 or vice versa seamlessly. How to achieve this? and what concerns we must todo?